# Is there an emailer widget for GWT?

Tags: email, gwt

I'm trying to write a lightweight emailer for a website in GWT (server side code in php, communication between client and server via JSON). Is there already a widget that does this? I know there are tons of GWT widgets out there, but I haven't been able to find this particular one.

Comment: And what would this emailer widget do exactly? Send an e-mail to the specified address(es)? TextBox/TextArea + some simple (I'm sure there are gazillions of tutorials on this) code for sending e-mails on the server side - what exactly is the problem? (I need to level up my mind reading abilities :/)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt such a common widget exists, just because it relies so heavily on knowing the interface with the server, and that interface is different for everybody.

It's a pretty easy thing to write yourself, though. It's as easy as adding a few textboxes and a textarea, a button to send the request to the server using a `RequestBuilder` with the correct POST parameters and display a message on success/failure.

If you have any more specific questions, feel free to ask, but that'd be the general idea of it.